# Can one save raw data corresponding to a Pybind11 class

Tags: pybind11

I'd like to be able to save raw byte array containing the data matching a (packed) C++ class exposed by Pybind11. Is this possible? It will really help with unit testing some C++ code. It would also be nice to do the reverse, but it isn't crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this. I added a template function in the pybind wrapper which returns a numpy byte array:

```
// Convert the object contents to a numpy byte array
template <class T> 
c_pyarray GetBytes(T& params) {  
  auto size = sizeof(T);
  auto output = py::array_t<uint8_t>(size);
  uint8_t* obase_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(output.request().ptr);
  uint8_t* thisPtr = (uint8_t*)&params;
  copy(thisPtr, thisPtr + size, obase_ptr);
  return output;
}
```